# Function that increments a number if it is not greater than the upper bound, otherwise resets to lower bound

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need a mathematical function that uses a current number (n) to determine the next number by incrementing it, but should not increment when I have gotten to the upper bound, rather it should reset it.

Example range of values `0, 1, 2, 3`.

When `n = 1` the function should give me `2`,

when `n = 2` I should get `3`,

but when `n = 3` I should get `0`.

Comment: What would you like to happen for $n=4$ ? Does it get $1$ or $0$ ?

Comment: @MattiP, 0 will be better any number >= the upper bound should reset to lower bound

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$
f(n) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
n+1 &~\text{if}~n<\text{max} \\
0 &~\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
?

Comment: I know of this and I have always used it, just needed something else with no condition.

Comment: If you want the same result with no if-sentences, you can use (a little bit weird-looking)
$$
f(n) = \min(x+1,m)-\frac{m}{2}\left(1+\text{sign}{(x-m+1)} \right)
$$
where $m$ is the maximum value and $\text{sign}$ is the sign function (-1 for negative numbers, +1 for positive numbers)

Answer (score 1):

If you lower bound is $0$ and your upper bound is $m$ then

$f(n) = n+1 \mod m$

will work. More generally, if you lower bound is $a$ and your upper bound is $b$ then

$f(n) = a + (n - a + 1 \mod b-a)$

Comment: What does `mod` stand for, and is `n` position or the value?

Comment: @JohnDavid $n$ is the value to which you apply the function $f$; $\text{mod}$ is the modulo operator and $p \mod q$ is the remainder when $p$ is divided by $q$, and takes values from $0$ to $q-1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.